# Remove Scroll event listener used in conjection with throttling function

Tags: javascript

I have function which I call **which opens a particular view** on my page.

```
function dayViewOpen(target){
         var date = getDate();
          ..
          ..
          ..
        document.addEventListener('scroll',throttle(function(event){
            scrollAddData(date);
        },10));
}
```

similarly I have a function to close that particular view

```
 function dayViewClose(target){
        ..
        ..


    }
```

**everything till now its working perfectly.** But problems start arising when I have to remove the earlier added event listener. I.e I have to remove the event listener when i call the function dayViewclose();

I get it that we need to have a **reference to listener** to remove it, so I when i do it like this.

```
var handler = throttle(function(event){
                scrollAddData();
            },10);

 function dayViewOpen(target){
         var date = getDate();
          ..
          ..
          ..
        document.addEventListener('scroll',handler,false);
}

 function dayViewClose(target){
        ..
        ..

        //remove earlier added event listener
       document.removeEventListener('scroll',handler,false);
    }
```

- then I am not able to pass the **date** parameter to the to my handler ( **how can i pass the date parameter to the handler** ) and
- Even if i let go of the date param then also i am not able to remove the handler with removeEvent Listener. ( **how can i remove the event listener properly** )

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try declaring the event listener outside, but setting it inside:

```
var handler;

function dayViewOpen(target){
    var date = getDate();
    /* ... */
    handler = throttle(function(event){
        scrollAddData(date);
    }, 10);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', handler, false);
}

function dayViewClose(target){
    /* ... */
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', handler, false);
}
```

Comment: this worked... thanks...can you please also tell me how to pass the date param to handler if declare it outside rather than inside...???

Comment: @bhavya_w Since `date` is a local variable, if you want to use it you must set `handler` inside `dayViewOpen`.

Comment: can I not pass it as a argument to the handler..?? If handler is declared outside..